# Create a SharePoint List item when an Outlook/Teams/group event is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, powerapp, pnp-provision, outlook-add-in

In SharePoint Online I want to create sub-items in Document library/List and wish to reference a Teams, Group or Outlook calendar event.

Is it possible to create a SharePoint List item when an event is created in the above calendars?  Then this could be used as a lookup for other document libraries.

Alternatively, is there an Outlook equivalent custom calendar that I can add to SharePoint that allows the same functionality (Create Team meetings, etc ..). Potentially I could add additional functionality to allow a SharePoint list item to be created

I'm looking for an option that can be deployed easily as want to automate the replication of solution for many projects. I think using Power Automate / Power Apps may not be suitable as I cannot create replications easily.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize a SharePoint Online Calendar with Outlook.

**Please the following steps:**

- Sign in the site collection as an admin and create a **Calendar App**.
- Go to the Calendar List page, click **CALENDAR** ribbon page, and then click on "**Connect to Outlook**" option and it will ask for a permission to open Outlook.

[image]

- Click **Yes** and it will open in Outlook. It will prompt you to add the user account and password; enter the user account, password and click on calendar option in Outlook, which is shown in the screenshot given below.

[image]

- We can see **two Outlook calendars**. On Outlook, we can uncheck unwanted from here and select, which we need.
- Just add the Event or Meeting here or on the SharePoint Calendar List and it will take an effect i.e. either updating from Outlook or Office 365 SPO calendar list.

[image]

More information, please refer to this article:

- [How to create and customize SharePoint Calendar](https://www.winwire.com/customize-sharepoint-office365-calendar/)

Comment: I've sync'ed up the SP online calendar to Outlook on-prem. Working in Outlook, I am able to add an event in the SP calendar.  This functionality appears to be missing from  OWA. i.e. After syncing, I cannot see SP calendar in OWA.